# Hudson continuous-integration - How to Aggregate the archived artifacts?

Tags: build, automation, continuous-integration, build-automation

The Hudson CI Server has a configuration option called "Aggregate the archived artifacts".
If I'm right, this option is used to share previously build artefact's across other builds/jobs. I have tried it, but it seems not working for me. How would the correct setup looks like? (PHAR packages are similar to JAR but for PHP)

## My current workspace layout:

- build
- lib/php
- src/php

**Job FOO:**

- FOO/workspace/BAR/build/foo.phar

**Job BAR:**

- BAR/workspace/BAR/build/bar.phar
- BAR/workspace/BAR/lib/php/foo.phar

## Hudson Job configuration for BAR:

**Aggregate the archived artifacts (checked)**

**Job to aggregate:** FOO (selected)

**Artifacts to copy:** **/build/*.phar

**Shared directory:** BAR/lib/php

Any suggestions are welcomed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This could be a version/plugin thing, but the version of Hudson we are using talks about "Archive the artifacts" and "Aggregate downstream test results" - is there a chance you are confusing the two terms?  The first - archiving - simply allows you to show the created artifacts from the job.  I am not totally sure what the second one does, as we do not use it.  However, I see from a search that the help documentation states:

> "Because tests often dominates the
>   execution time, a Hudson best practice
>   involves splitting test executions
>   into different jobs, possibly in
>   multiple different jobs.
>
> When you do that, setting test
>   aggregation is a convenient way of
>   collecting all the test results from
>   such downstream test jobs and display
>   it along with the build that they are
>   testing. In this way, people can see
>   the overall test status of the given
>   build quickly."

Comment: Yes, i know the difference between "Archiving" and "Aggregate". So I'm talking about the second one, you talked about. My situation is nearly the same as in the documentation manifested. I need the artefact's from a previous job to build the following one.

Comment: Maybe I am reading it wrong, but the aggregation seems to be aggregating test results, not artifacts.  And I did not mean to offend if I did - I was simply making sure that we were talking about the same thing :)